# Convert LocalDateTime to Date with saving timezone

Tags: java, date, timezone

On the lower level I create `LocalDateTime` object with user-specified timezone, but then, when I call some methods, I need to convert `LocalDateTime` to old `Date`.

How can I do this **with saving timezone**? I know how to convert from `LocalDateTime` to `Date`, **I just need to save timezone**.

Comment: may i ask why you want to convert to date? have you looked into ZonedDateTime class?

Comment: @RahulSharma because I have API which works with `Date` object.

Comment: fair enough. I thought ZonedDateTime would help since it is quite easy to use (personal opinion) , but it seems inapplicable in your case.

Comment: Literally the first code snippet in the accepted answer shows how to preserve the timezone. This is very much a duplicate.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `new Date()` applying system default timezone, and the secong argument provides system default timezone too.

Comment: Adapt it to use the timezone of your choice. The term _local_ in the type name `LocalDateTime` implies your system default.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I can't get timezone from `LocalDateTime`. It is already converted.

Comment: @RahulSharma I already do this in lower level. `zonedDateTime.toLocalDateTime();`

Comment: What does the first line of the [javadoc of `LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) say?  It's now unclear what you're asking about.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis so, you mean, when I convert `ZonedDateTime` to `LocalDateTime`, I already lost my timezone?

Comment: More or less, yes.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ok, thanks. Sorry for that dispute :)

Comment: You don't have to apologize. Just understand that a duplicate is not a bad thing. The purpose is to lead you to the answer.